# Strange problem with JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

Hi Masters Of Web Development,
first I want to say that I did not believe in my eyes - I've got a piece of javascript that works just fine in IE7, and don't in Firefox!!! :)))) That was little joke. :)
So I already told you the problem (it wasn't joke), now I'm pasting the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

<!-- This script and many more are available free online at -->
<!-- The JavaScript Source!! http://javascript.internet.com -->

<!-- Begin
var ms;
ms = %%CONTENT_REFRESH%% - 5;
var stop;
stop = 0;
var myvalue;

function display() {
    if (!stop) {
        setTimeout("display();", 1000);
    }
    thetime.value = myvalue;
}
function recalc() {
    var hours;
    var minutes;
    var seconds;

    ms = ms - 1;
    hours = Math.floor(ms / 3600);
    minutes = Math.floor(ms / 60);
    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0"+minutes;
    }
    seconds = ms - (minutes*60) - (hours*3600);
    if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = "0"+seconds;
    }
    myvalue = hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds;
    thetime.value = myvalue;
    if (myvalue == "0:00:00") {
        stop = 1;
    }
    if (!stop) {
        setTimeout("recalc();", 1000);
    }
}
// End -->
</SCRIPT>
```

This is very old script I know that. It takes my current remaining song time, from my winamp and countdowns in site. But as I said, it does not work in Firefox.

Body and code that calls countdown timer looks like this:

```
<body class="playlist_body" onLoad="recalc();display();">

Time Left In Song: <INPUT align="center" TYPE="text" Name="thetime" size=5 />

</body>
```

//Edit: I look at FireBug, and I saw the following error:

```
thetime is not defined
recalc()playlist.cgi (line 87)
function onload(event) { recalc(); display(); }(load )1 (line 2)
error source line: [Break on this error] thetime.value = myvalue;\n
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in Firefox's Javascript console, or the Firebug console?

Comment: HOW MUCH STUPID I CAN BE SOMETIMES!!! I forgot to look in FireBug! Yes, it gave error. I'm editing my question with the Error in it! Thanks Jason! :)

Comment: So what happens when you define 'thetime' properly?

Comment: You should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513286/document-getelementbyidselage-vs-document-myforms-selage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that it's accessing DOM elements by name.

Add the following code to the top to declare a variable for the `thetime` element, add `id="thetime"` to the `INPUT`, and add a call to `init();` in `onload` in the `body` element.

```
var thetime;

function init() {
    thetime = document.getElementById('thetime');
}
```

---

By the way, you can replace the textbox with a regular `DIV` element by setting the `div`'s ID to `thetime`, and replacing `thetime.value` with `thetime.innerHTML`.

Also, it's better to call setTimeout with a function instead of a string; you should replace `"display();"` and `"recalc();"` with `display` and `recalc` respectively.

Comment: Well... it looks like a clever decision, but... It doesn't talk to me nothing. If... I may ask you to wright it to me...

Comment: What happens when you try? Make sure you added `init();` to the beginning of `onload=`.

Comment: DAMN!!! It wont work before, because I added init(); after recalc and display! Now when you told me, to add it in the begining, it works JUST FINE!!! Thanks a lot man! :))

Answer (score 3):

IE has a "feature" where an element with a  name attribute is placed in the window object, eg.

```
<div name=foo></div>
```

Will give you a variable "foo" -- this is non-standard, you should do

```
document.getElementByName("foo")
```

To get the timer output element.

Comment: It would be document.getElementsByName("foo")[0]. "getElementByName" is not a function

Comment: I didn't understand anything... I'm newby with this... :(

Answer (score 0):

```
var thetime = document.getElementById("thetime");
```

and add id="thetime" instead of just name="thetime" to the input

Comment: This will fail because the element won't exit yet.

Comment: that depends on where you do it.