# form validation using javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to validate my registration form, but its not working , i google it but not found a solution. 
here is my javascript code :

```
      <script>
      function validateForm() {
      var x = document.forms["form"]["firstname"].value;
      if (x==null || x=="") {
      alert("First name must be filled out");
      return false;
      }
      }
      </script>
```

and my form is :

```
    <form name="form" id="form" action="register.php" method="post" 
    enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateForm()">

       <span class="required">*</span> First Name:</td>
       <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="" />
       <input type="submit" value="Continue" class="button" />

    </form>
```

Comment: I just want to note a security flaw I see, you should also validate this on the server side. I can easily bypass JavaScript making this layer of security useless. For example someone could post the data using the RESTful web client extension in chrome and completely bypass the first name field or make it super loooong...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513286/document-getelementbyid-selage-vs-document-myforms-selage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setup for this is incorrect.  So, I've edited it to show a better way.  Not the perfect way, but closer to what you've already written.

Change it around like this:

```
 <form name="form" id="form" action="register.php" method="post" 
    enctype="multipart/form-data">

       <span class="required">*</span> First Name:</td>
       <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="" />
       <input type="button" value="Continue" class="button" onclick="validateForm()" />

    </form>
```

Then, do the submission if it passes:

```
<script>
diItPass=1;
      function validateForm() {
      var x = document.forms["form"]["firstname"].value;
      if (x==null || x=="") {
      alert("First name must be filled out");
      didItPass=0;
if (didItPass==1) { document.getElementById("form").submit() }


      }
      }
      </script>
```

The idea being, to set a variable to show if the form passed submission.  If it does, submit it.  If it doesn't show the alert, and do nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You should use document.getElementById to get the value of the firstname input. I have done a fiddle here if you want to see it working: http://jsfiddle.net/365qebye/1/

```
  function validateForm() {          
      var x = document.getElementById("firstname").value;          
      if (x === null || x === "") {
          alert("First name must be filled out");
          return false;
      }
  }
```